# Find nth Root of a number in C++

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to make a maths library and one of the functions finds a nth root of a float.

My current expression is -

```
value = value ^ 1/rootValue
```

but I'm getting an error because I'm using a float.
Is there another method of solving this?

Comment: Lots of methods: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: @MarcB: That's fine for finding roots of a function, but the question is about finding roots of a number.

Comment: @mikea: Not really. Unless you're implementing this from scratch as a learning exercise, you'd use the standard library when appropriate.

Comment: @MikeSeymour There is a simple reason for this ambiguity. `N`th root of a number `K` is a root of the function `f(x) = x^N - K`.

Comment: @ŁukaszKidziński: Indeed; general root-finding algorithms might be useful if you wanted to solve this from (more or less) first principles. But there are [more specific algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm) for this particular case, and the standard library if this isn't an exercise for learning numeric techniques.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Sure, I was rather referring to "Not really", but now I see what you meant by the rest of the comment :)

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `^` means, in C and C++ that's the XOR operation, not a power.

Answer (score 23):

There is no "power" operator in C++; `^` is the bitwise exclusive-or operator, which is only applicable to integers.

Instead, there is a function in the standard library:

```
#include <cmath>

value = std::pow(value, 1.0/root);
```

Answer (score 3):

`^` is not what you want here. It is a bitwise exclusive-OR operator.

Use

```
#include <math.h>
```

and then

```
value = pow(value, 1/rootvalue)
```

---

Reference for `pow`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Answer (score 0):

The `^`  operator does not do what you think - it is not a power operator but a bitwise XOR.

Look at [`pow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) from the `math` library.

Answer (score 0):

**^** is  **Bitwise XOR** operator.
Use the **pow()** function for it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm),

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
double exp(double, double);
double n_root_(double, double);
int main()
{
    double v = n_root_(27,3);
    cout << v << endl;
    return 0;
}

double exp(double a, double b){
    double t(1);
    for(int i = 0;i<b;++i)
        t *= a;
    return t;
}
double n_root_(double num, double n_){
    double x;
    double A(num);
    double dx;
    double eps(10e-6);
    double n(n_);
    x = A * 0.5;
    dx = (A/exp(x,n-1)-x)/n;
    while(dx >= eps || dx <= -eps){
        x = x + dx;
        dx = (A/exp(x,n-1)-x)/n;
    }
   return x;
}
```

Comment: `double exp(double a, double b)` what a horribly unhelpful function signature!

Comment: Is this an efficient alternative to using `pow(x, 1/root)`?